# Scipy.optimize.newton: RunTimeError

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a kind of strange problem and I don't know how to handle it. I have a function I'd like to optimize with newton method. But it always gives me a runtime error:

```
def zmax_bound_dry(x):
    return 23.56 * (1/0.09) + 30.91*math.log1p(1+(x/30.91))

scipy.optimize.newton(zmax_bound_dry, x0=80)
```

If I call the function with my initial guess 80 it works, but the newton optimization doesn't converge as it gives a ValueError. I think it is due to the log but the manual call with the initial guess works, so the algorithm should return at least the initial guess, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of troubleshooting these sorts of things is to patch your function to print the value of the argument on each iteration:

```
In [9]: def zmax_bound_dry(x):
          print(x)
          return 23.56 * (1/0.09) + 30.91*math.log1p(1+(x/30.91))
   ...: 

In [10]: newton(zmax_bound_dry, 80)
80
80.0081
-1337.1783578
```

Now it clear what's going on: the argument of the log goes negative.

Why does it do this is a separate matter. BTW, `optimize.newton` tries to locate a root, not an extemum (so when you say "optimize", make sure you mean to mean what you do); Using `log1p(1 + x)` is a tad strange because log1p is already `log(1+x)`.